# Unable to register View to ViewModel manually using Prism.Mvvm.ViewModelLocationProvider

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, prism

**Folder structure -**

```
Project Named 'Home'
|> Views > HomeView.xaml
|> ViewModels > HomeViewModel.cs
|> HomeModule.cs (an IModule class)
```

**HomeView.XAML** (Note: AutoWireViewModel is set to FALSE)

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Tally.Sync.Home.Views.HomeView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tally.Sync.Home.Views"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="False"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="28"
            Text="{Binding Message}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**HomeViewModel.cs**

```
public class HomeViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _message = "Hi There!";
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _message, value); }
    }

    public HomeViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

**HomeModule.cs**

```
public class HomeModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public HomeModule(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
    {
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegion", typeof(HomeView));
    }

    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<HomeView, HomeViewModel>();
    }
}
```

As you can see I am registering the HomeView & HomeViewModel with the `ViewModelLocationProvider`. But this doesn't work. My code is running as expected when the `AutoWireViewModel` is set to `True`

**What am I doing wrong?** I know I can auto wire it, but I am trying to learn Prism and one of videos by Brian Lagunas mentions wiring manually is faster as reflection won't be required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you register views and view models manually to the view model locator, you still have to enable auto-wiring in the view model, it will just change **how** the `ViewModelLocator` resolves the view and its view model. Setting `False` will disable it, so it does not resolve anything.

```
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
```

As you can see from the reference [source](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/3ab9483145e383d85f69a8660835de4a7da80cdf/src/Prism.Core/Mvvm/ViewModelLocationProvider.cs#L89) for `ViewModelLocationProvider`, registered views will be checked first when resolving the view model. If there are no registrations, the fallback to resolving with the naming convention via reflection will be used.

```
public static void AutoWireViewModelChanged(object view, Action<object, object> setDataContextCallback)
{
   object viewModel = GetViewModelForView(view);

   if (viewModel == null)
   {
      // Try to resolve the view model via regsitrations
      var viewModelType = GetViewModelTypeForView(view.GetType());

      // If views and view models are not registerd, fallback to reflection
      if (viewModelType == null)
         viewModelType = _defaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver(view.GetType());

      //...
   }

   // ...
}
```

As the `ViewModelLocator` will resolve the view both via registration or the naming convention fallback, you did not notice a difference. If you rename your `HomeViewModel` to `HomeFooBar` or anything else that does not fit the naming convention, the fallback will fail and you will see that it works as described above.

> [...] wiring manually is faster as reflection won't be required.

I think that there are many misunderstandings concerning reflection. In this case with a few views you will not even notice any difference and it is much more convenient. Do not optimize prematurely.

Comment: Thank you! This makes so much sense once you look at the source. And also a big thanks on making me realize I need to refer the source - I was relying just on documentation and setting it to false seemed intuitive for manual wiring.